# Coeffiecient of body of friction

Tags: physics

A body of weight 50N is placed on a smooth surface II the force required to move the body on the rough surface is 30N the coefficient of friction is

The answer is 0.60.
could someone explain?

Comment: How exactly did you screw up this badly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a physics question not related to electrical engineering.

Comment: I bet he tries to put a box of transistors in motions using a high end linear servo drive. Otherwise it's indeed not related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F: Frictional resistance force
u: coefficient of kinetic friction
N: Normal force

F = u * N          -- The formula,
30N = u * 50N      -- Substitute in the values,
30N / 50N = u      -- Perform simple algebra,
.6 = u             -- Simplify.
```